# Hibernate : Force lazy-loadding on eager field

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, eager-loading

One of our model object in our application has many fields configured to be eagerly fetched like so:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "field")
public Field getField() {
    return this.field;
}
```

However I sometime do not need these information, which slow down my queries for nothing. I cannot change the behaviour and use `FetchType.LAZY` instead as I've no idea what will be the impact on the whole application (legacy...). Is there a way to simply tell `hibernate` to fetch nothing, *except* if it is specified in the query?

Comment: Are you using hql or criteria?

Comment: HQL mainly (named query) but if needed I can switch to criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked there was no proper solution provided by hibernate, so I ended up with this solution:

- Configured the problematic references as `LAZY`.
- All affected service methods (that used these models) got an overloaded version with `boolean forceEager`
- by default all existing functions were refactored to call the new ones with `forceEager=true`
- and here comes the trick: as a means of "forcing the eager fetching" I found nothing better than actually accessing the proxied (lazy-fetched) objects. In case for example a lazily referenced list doing `list.size()` will force Hibernate to load the full list, hence the service returns with fully fetched object.

In case of more than one layer in your objectstructure is affected, you need to traverse through the whole hierarchy and access every lazily loaded object from top to bottom.

*This is a bit error-prone solution, so you need to handle it with care.*

Answer (score 0):

If its possible to switch to Criteria for this query, you could use FetchMode.SELECT for the field property

```
crit.setFetchMode("field", FetchMode.SELECT);
```

Comment: Thanks for you repl. I tried it but nothing changed, I still have many SELECT queries. I think my only solution will be to leave it as or change everything to LAZY and correct all broken codes...