# Force lazy loading of usually eager attributes

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eager-loading

How do I force a specific query to lazy load an attribute, that usually has eager loading?
EntityGraphType.FETCH isn't working.

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name="negGraphName",attributeNodes={
      @NamedAttributeNode("name"),
      @NamedAttributeNode("grup")})
class User{
  private String name;  

  @ManyToOne
  private UserGroup grup;

  @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  protected Set<Authority> authoritiesList;
}

interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<String, User>{
  @EntityGraph(value="negGraphName", type=EntityGraphType.FETCH)
  @Query("<custom query here>")
  private Collection<User> getUsersInSpecialQuery(@Param("paramName") String paramName);
}
```

basically, when I call `userRepository.getUsersInSpecialQuery()` the initial query joins in object, and doesn't join in authority, however then Hibernate anyway initializes the authorities list with A SEPARATE SQL QUERY PER USER RESULT, which is highly inefficient. Also, it initializes DomainObject object graph parent which is not even marked as Eager.

Disabling `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` on authorityList disabled the additional per-user queries, but I still want it eagerly fetched for all other queries.

`EntityGraphType.Fetch`'s javadoc says:

> When the javax.persistence.fetchgraph property is used to specify an
>   entity graph, attributes that are specified by attribute nodes of the
>   entity graph are treated as FetchType.EAGER and attributes that are
>   not specified are treated as FetchType.LAZY

however clearly this is not the case for me

---

[Hibernate : Force lazy-loadding on eager field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959677/hibernate-force-lazy-loadding-on-eager-field) <-- Doesn't have a solution

[Fetch Type LAZY still causes Eager loading Hibernate Spring data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282018/fetch-type-lazy-still-causes-eager-loading-hibernate-spring-data) <-- claims the problem is that the lazy attribute was loaded by viewing, however in my case, I stepped through in hibernate, and it was during materialization of the User object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant make an EAGER assosciation LAZY. I suggest you make it LAZY and in all queries where you want it EAGERly JOIN FETCH the `authoritiesList` so they are effectively EAGER then.

Another option is a *subentity* which is basically the same as your current user entity, mapped to the same DB table but without the relationship you dont want:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SAME_TABLE_AS_USER_ENTITY")
class BasicUser{
  private String name;  

  @ManyToOne
  private UserGroup grup;

}
```

Another option would be inheritance.

Comment: what about `EntityGraphType.Fetch`. doesn't it specifially say it will only eagerly load the mentioned attributes, and the rest will be lazy-loaded?

Comment: From javax.persistence.QueryHints.HINT_FETCHGRAPH: `Hint providing a "fetchgraph" EntityGraph. Attributes explicitly specified as AttributeNodes are treated as FetchType.EAGER (via join fetch or subsequent select).
Note: Currently, attributes that are not specified are treated as FetchType.LAZY or FetchType.EAGER depending on the attribute’s definition in metadata, rather than forcing FetchType.LAZY.`

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understand. spring-data's `EntityGraphTypes` refer to different things. This enum is just a shortcut for the following jpa query hints

- `javax.persistence.fetchgraph` refers to how the query is *built*,
- `javax.persistance.loadgraph` refers to how the objects are populated from the result set.

so there is no answer past what @Robert_Niestroj recommended